# CKEditor: Media plugin and resizing pictures

Tags: drupal, ckeditor

I am using CKEditor on Drupal 7. I have a button for inserting media on my toolbar: [image: CKEditor Media icon]

The button brings up this screen:
[image: CKEditor media overlay]

How do I define a new display option to be listed under the "Display as" option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'Display as' option in CKEditor shows list of view modes allowed for given media type. If using [Display Suite](https://www.drupal.org/project/ds) module, you may add new custom view mode at `/admin/structure/ds/view_modes`:

[image: Display Suite - list of view modes]

[image: Display Suite - add new view mode]

Then go to `/admin/structure/file-types/manage/image/display` and check newly added view mode under 'Custom display settings' (and you may also uncheck unnecessary view modes here):

[image: Image - manage display - check new view mode]

Finally, go to the next tab `/admin/structure/file-types/manage/image/file-display` and then click on your new view mode:

[image: Image - manage file display]

There, check 'Image' and set image style under 'Display settings' below:

[image: Image - manage file display - check Image]

After these steps, your new view mode will appear in CKEditor.

Comment: Stas, thank you very much! you learnt me something new again.

Anyway, it doesn't work. You can try it on our common project.

Comment: No, it works :) You wanted new image style in CKEditor, and you got it :) If you now want some specific image styling, you need to create new image formatter, which will be shown on the last screen under "Manage file display" tab.

Answer (score 0):

You probably can do it by going to /admin/structure/file-types and editing the display options of the file type you want to attach a new display to.